# Comaparing 2 columns in table A to 2 columns in table b

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables that contain a list of first and second names

In table1 columns A & B are surname and firstname
in table 2 columns E & F are surname and firstname

I need a formula that checks  if a name appears in both tables i.e A2+B2 appear in E+F return true..

i've tried a mixture of IF, Index, Match, VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP but i just keep getting errors returned, i'm totally outwith my depth.

if someone can point me in the right direction that be great.

thanks

Comment: Just use `COUNTIFS()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way:

- In table 1, concatenate surname+name, in a new column
- In table 2, concatenate surname+name, in a new column
- In a new sheet create two new columns:

  1. In the first one, bring all the concatenated surname+name values from table 1
  2. In the second one use MATCH to compare the value in the first column (of the new sheet) with the column of concatenated values of table 2 (it will give you the number of row where the match happens - combine it with ISNUMBER and you'll get a TRUE/FALSE result)